# How many police officers were killed in the police station in The Terminator?

Tags: the-terminator

In the movie *The Terminator*, when the T-800 comes to the police station to find Sarah Connor to kill, he kills most of the police.

**How many police officers were killed in this scene?**

Answer (score 26, accepted):

We see one killed by the car, and a further fourteen shot (and killed?) during the four minute sequence. We also see him firing two separate volleys into a room, presumably killing at least two more officers.

> 

The tallies with the description in *T2: Judgement Day* of the incident.

> <sub><sup>"He killed seventeen police officers that night"</sup></sub>

Comment: It's unsurprising that every shot is a kill, because the Terminator has "detailed files on human anatomy" and therefore would know where to aim to maximize the chances of killing someone.

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE this is later reinforced in T2, when its ordered not to kill. The Terminator is perfectly capable of making 100% non-lethal gunshots. The opposite, being far easier, is then proven.

Answer (score 31):

According to the [T2 shooting script](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Terminator-2-Judgement-Day.html), seventeen.

> **DETECTIVE WEATHERSBY (O.S.)**: *These were taken at the West Highland police station in 1984. You were there.*
>
> **MOSSBERG**: *He killed seventeen police officers that night. Recognize him?*

Comment: Shooting script. **Pun intended**

Comment: First thing that came to mind when I saw the question was: I'm practically sure they addressed that in the second movie.